# React Scroll to top not working? New solutions needed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm trying to scroll to the top of the screen when the user submits a form. The answers on stacked overflow don't seem to work for me.

here's my code:

```
handleClick (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.calculateScore();
    this.setState({submittingQuiz: true});

    // let myPage = document.querySelector('body');
    // myPage.scrollTo(0,0); Couldn't get this way to work either

    window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem. I have some styling I think may be messing with it..

```
html {
  background-image: url('./tupac.jpeg');
  background-position-y: -580px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

Anyone got a clue?
```

Comment: You have `overflow: hidden` but you’re not at the top of the view? You’re scrolling a different element, not window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because the `body` has a `height: 100vh;` or some main container of the application has the same `height: 100vh;`

Try remove `height: 100vh;` on `body` and the main container of the application and test it again.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and, as the marked solution mentions, removing `height: 100vh` solved the issue for me. However, my website was not functioning properly without `height: 100vh` (elements would reach the very bottom of the page even with sufficient margin/padding).

If you need `height: 100vh`, then I would recommend using [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), instead of [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), with the element being some element near or at the top of your website.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue trying to use `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` inside `useEffect`. No `height: 100vh` in my code.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

did the trick, no actual timeout needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like `height: 100vh` in the parent it won't work, but you can use this approach.

```
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
    if (container) {
     container.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
```

You can give a container `<div style={{ position: 'absoulte', top: '-10px' }} />`

`-10px` if you need to go all the way to top, you give negative margin, to position div at the top (or where you want to scroll), and you are ready to go.

also see [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)